# Finding all the matches from a string using regex

Tags: java, regex

I've a string and I would like to find all the matches followed by a text. for ex:

following is my string.

```
{"testAcc":"90808023", "testAddress1":"1 mst","testCity":"acbd","testState":"TE","name":"John"}
```

I'm trying to match all the values that starts with "test" and ends with either Address1, City or State. Following is what I tried, But it is not working.

```
\"test(Address1|City|State|)\"\s*:\s*\"(.*?)\"
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: How do you compile and execute the regex? Can you show the code, not only the regex? Also, please define "not working". Is it matching nothing at all, is it matching the wrong parts of the string, is it matching some parts, but not others?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to parse JSON using regular expressions. You should use a JSON library like Jackson or GSON. Also, in using regex, if you want to match up to a delimiter, you can use a reluctant quantifier like `(.*?)` but the regex engine may have to backtrack multiple times to satisfy the expression. It is much better to say "all characters that are not the closing delimiter" i.e. `([^"]*)`. I see this mistake made by a *lot* of developers.

Comment: Of course, neither of those would work on `{ "name" : "John \"Big Guy\" Smith" }`, which is why you should use a library to parse JSON.

Answer (score -1):

As a `String`:

```java
"\"test(Address1|City|State)\"\\s*:\\s*\"[^\"]*\""
```

Use `find`.

Any questions?